# Logon failure with Ruby Httparty and Json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, httparty

i was trying to log in into a site which has the following API:
POST https://www.Thesite.com/Account/LogOn
post JSON `data:{UserName:xxx,Pasword:xxx,SecondFactor:[optional]}`
save the `CookieContainer` & `header["SecretKey"]` to pass for next calls, else you will get 409 conflict
I wrote the following Ruby script, but the response is : enter username and password
what is wrong?

```
!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "rubygems"
require "httparty"

include HTTParty 

class TheSite   
  base_uri 'https://www.Thesite.com'
  def initialize(u, p)
    @data = {:UserName => u, :Pasword => p}.to_json
    response = self.class.get('/Account/LogOn')
    response = self.class.post(
      '/Account/LogOn',
       :data => @data,
       :headers=>{'SecretKey'=>response.headers['Set-Cookie']})
       @cookie = response.request.options[:headers]['cookie']
    puts response
  end
end

thesite = Thesite.new('myuser', 'mypassword')
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a fair bit incorrect here:

- You don't need to JSONify the data, but you need to set the correct JSON headers. A lot of people do this don't worry.
- The whole cookie thing comes after the request, not in it.
- Some missing brackets here swell.

Here's a working example:

```
!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "rubygems"
require "httparty"

include HTTParty 

class TheSite   
  base_uri 'https://www.Thesite.com'
  def initialize(u, p)
    @data = {
      :UserName => u,
      :Password => p
    } 
    res = self.class.post('Account/LogOn', 
                          :body => @data, 
                          :options => {
                            :headers => { 
                              'ContentType' => 'application/json', 
                              'Accept'      => 'application/json',
                              'SecretKey'   => res.headers['Set-Cookie']                          
                            }
                          }
                         )
    if res.code == 200
      @cookie = res.request.options[:headers]['Cookie']
      # do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Still has err in line:"@cookie = res.request.options[:headers]['Cookie']".It gives : `initialize': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError).The request.options puts "{:limit=>5, :assume_utf16_is_big_endian=>true, :default_params=>{}, :follow_redirects=>true, :parser=>HTTParty::Parser, :connection_adapter=>HTTParty::ConnectionAdapter, :base_uri=>"https://www.Thesite", :body=>{:UserName=>"user", :Password=>"pass"}, :options=>{:headers=>{"ContentType"=>"application/json", "Accept"=>"application/json", "Cookie"=>".ASPXAUTH=; expires=Mon, 11-Oct-1999 22:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly"}}}

Comment: still does not work...Same error. What info would u like to get ? Thx

Comment: @user3047355 basically whatever is in your console around that request